# Forks and PIDs in C

Tags: c, sockets, fork, pid, child-process

I'm finding some difficulties with this C exercise: I'm asked to create a server socket which reads (through an infinite loop) a string from the input stream. If the string reads "self", the server prints on the output stream the server's own pid. If it reads "fork", it calls the fork() function and prints the child's pid. 
I was thinking of including these lines inside the while loop

```
if (strcmp(val,"self")==0) sprintf(result,"%d\n",getpid());
else if (strcmp(val,"fork")==0){
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) sprintf(result, "%d\n", getpid());
```

I tested it and it actually works fine when I write "self" or "fork" just once. If I try to issue the "fork" command more than once it gets "stuck", meaning that I have to repeat the command two or three times before I can actually get the result I need.

Here is an example of what I do (I use telnet to test the server):

```
 Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
self
4313
fork
4324
fork
fork
self
4313
fork
fork
fork 
4327
fork
fork 
fork
4328
```

Any ideas?

Comment: We need to see the rest of the `fork` code. Why are you outputing in the child? What does the child do after it outputs?

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE: http://www.sscce.org/

Answer (score 3):

You need to manage the child after you've forked. The first thing to do after forking is to check whether you're the parent or the child process, then do different things based on where you are.

**In the child:**

- Do whatever you need to do, then exit. From your description the child may not need to do anything, in which case it can exit immediately.

  If you don't exit then the child will continue on doing the same thing as the parent. It will step on its parent's toes, reading the parent's input and messing up its output and causing other sorts of minor havoc.

  It's recommended to exit child processes with `_Exit()`, not `exit()`. `exit()` will run cleanup code like flushing stdio buffers that you really only want the parent to run.

**In the parent:**

- Get the child's PID and print it.
- Wait for the child to exit with `wait()`.

  The child is supposed to exit immediately, so the wait shouldn't block for long. Waiting for the child ensures the child process is cleaned up and doesn't become a [zombie process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process).

Comment: You *could* just `SIG_IGN` `SIGCHLD` explicitly, rather than `wait()`.